# Regex String Doesn't Start or End With Special Character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

SO buddies, greetings.  I have some password requirements I need to implement and one of the requirements is the string **cannot start or end with a special character**.  I did spend some time Googling around but my RegEx kung-fu is kimosabe level.

Just in case you're interested in some code, here's the **JavaScript**:
*Note: Yes, passwords are also validated on the server as well :)  The following snippet runs the RegEx tests and simply checks or x's the row item associated with the password rule.*

```
var validate = function(password){
        valid = true;

        var validation = [
            RegExp(/[a-z]/).test(password), RegExp(/[A-Z]/).test(password), RegExp(/\d/).test(password), 
            RegExp(/[-!#$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,./]/).test(password), !RegExp(/\s/).test(password), !RegExp("12345678").test(password), 
            !RegExp($('#txtUsername').val()).test(password), !RegExp("cisco").test(password), 
            !RegExp(/([a-z]|[0-9])\1\1\1/).test(password), (password.length > 7)
        ]

        $.each(validation, function(i){
            if(this == true)
                $('.form table tr').eq(i+1).attr('class', 'check');
            else{
                $('.form table tr').eq(i+1).attr('class', '');
                valid = false
            }
        });

        return(valid);

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the error but i see that the regex RegExp("12345678") doesn't have any delimiters, could that be it?

Comment: What's wrong with `/^[\d\w]+$/i`?

Comment: @rednaw there isn't any error in the present code, a new requirement has to be implemented. Based on the answer below it looks like I need something like `/^[^a-z].*/` but I need to include numbers as well.  In other words, I make sure the password both starts and ends with a letter or number.

Comment: @pixelbobby You probably only need a single regular expression to achieve what you want - please explain in words what you want to be a valid password

Comment: `(^[(a-z)|(A-Z)|(0-9)])` looks close. A valid password starts and ends with an alphanumeric (lower or uppercase).  In the regex to the left, I need to add or ends with.

Comment: @pixelbobby see edit to my answer below

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT:** The regular expression you want is:-

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9](.*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/
```

**Additional information**

In regular expressions `^` means 'beginning of string' and `$` means 'end of string', so for example:-

```
/^something$/
```

Matches

```
'something'
```

But not

```
'This is a string containing something and some other stuff'
```

You can negate characters using `[^-char to negate-]`, so

```
/^[^#&].*/
```

Matches any string that doesn't begin with a # or a &

Comment: This answer was still extremely helpful.

Comment: I'm going to give the answer to @rgvcorley because he provided the most effort and was first answer, although rednaw got the answer (close) and fast.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9](.*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/
```

This expression checks the following validations:

- No blank spaces at start and end
- No special characters at the end and beginning
- special characters allowed in between

Comment: what would be the regex, if it shouldn't allow special character in between?

Answer (score 1):

This regex should be what you want:

```
/^[0-9a-z].*[0-9a-z]$/
```

Comment: YES! `^[0-9a-zA-Z].*[0-9a-zA-Z]$`

Comment: This would not match string like 'p' or '1' which both start and end in either a character or a number

Comment: Are you sure? I tested the expression in my comment above on RegExr and it matched the following: password1, password, 1password...

Comment: @pixelbobby What I mean is it doesn't match a string that contains a single character which is alphanumeric (which matches your criteria, which was any string that began and ended with an alphanumeric character)

Comment: in other words the regular expression above also has the condition that the string must contain at least 2 characters.

Comment: You're welcome - regular expressions can be tricky, they are quite subtle but once you get the hang of them they can be quite fun to write!